# C++ undefine macros not working as expected

Tags: c++, macos, c-preprocessor

I have two programs to test the working of  `#undef`, but it is not working as expected.

test1.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

#define AB 1

void display(){
#ifdef AB
std::cout<<"yes"<<std::endl;
#endif
}

int main(){
display();
#undef AB
display();
}
```

output: `yes yes`

test2.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

#define AB 1

int main(){
#ifdef AB
std::cout<<"yes\n";
#endif

#undef AB

#ifdef AB
std::cout<<"yes\n";
#else
std::cout<<"no\n";
#endif
}
```

output : `yes no`

Why there is difference in the output even though the logic of both program is same?
Also is defining and undefinig macro thread-safe?

Comment: FWIW, from the tag you used: *A textual macro processor applied before compiling C and C++ language programs.*

Comment: `#undef` is not a time machine.

Comment: The logic of the two programs is not the same.  `#undef` of a macro only affects source code (which uses the macro) that is below the `#undef`  (i.e.  further down the source file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two programs are not the same!

Preprocessor macros are parsed and replaced during the *preprocessing* stage, before the *compiling* stage even sees the source code.  The preprocessor is a single-pass operation, top to bottom.  `#define` and `#undef` are processed in the order they are seen, and can alter the source code that the compiler eventually sees.

Regarding thread-safety, there are no threads involved during the *preprocessing* and *compiling* stages, only when the final compiled program is actually executed at runtime.

So, in your example:

In the first program, moving from top to bottom, `AB` is defined, then the `display()` code is reached, then `main()` is reached, and the `#undef` within in.  Since `AB` is defined inside the `display()` code, it outputs `yes`. The `#undef` in `main()` has no effect on what happens inside of `display()` since the `#undef` is after `display()`'s code.  And since `main()` makes two calls to `display()`, you see `yes` printed twice.

In the second program, moving top to bottom, `AB` is defined, then `main()` is entered, and `AB` is defined for the code that produces the first output, so it prints `yes`, but `AB` is undefined for the code that produces the second output, so it prints `no` instead.

If you were to manually perform the same replacements that the preprocessor makes, you will see that you have two very different programs:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

void display(){
std::cout<<"yes"<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
display();
display();
}
```

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(){
std::cout<<"yes\n";
std::cout<<"no\n";
}
```